# Measles according to the customs & beliefs

Tags: belief, customs, superstitions

I was a bit surprised to realize that there was no post relating to measles. Anything about it would help me, like:

- How it is viewed and what is its significance?
- Do the scriptures mention it as being a manifestation of a Goddess or the results of her anger?
- Is the treatment mentioned in the history?

Or is it merely superstition?

Comment: measles (is) was mere a superstition created by the later civilization.

Comment: @Creator, you mean there was nothing called measles which existed?

Comment: The Goddess to please to prevent measles, Shitala Devi holds a broom, water and a winnow, which was to show that if you kept your surroundings and food clean enough then you can prevent spreading of such diseases. Or in South India, we have Mariamman, whose worship involves tying up of neem leaves and worshipping, which is also extremely helpful. But people concentrated more on the pleasing Devi than on following the practices they symbolised - hence came the superstition.

Comment: There is Goddess in Ganas of Shiva who causes all diseases. To teach Humans a lesson, i think she causes diseases

Comment: in my locality shitla devi puja is done when suffering from measeles and chicken pox .